# React.js made a Custom Line Chart

Tags: reactjs, svg, charts, chart.js, linechart

i would like to made a line chart like this Image.
i have checked chart.js. but seems the UI is not able to do like the attach image.
Is there any ways to made this design out? Am i need to draw by svg by my onw?
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your question. You have an ReactJS app and need to build a component that renders an SVG chart?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky ,  yes , have an react js app,  need to build a chart  with design. but not must to use svg

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple example of SVG rendered with React:

```js
const MyChart = ({points}) => {
  const lines = points.reduce((result, point, index) => {
    if (index === 0) return [];
    const previous = points[index - 1];
    const line = {x1: previous.x, y1: previous.y, x2: point.x, y2: point.y};
    return [...result, line];
  }, []);

  return (
    <svg width="200" height="200">
      
      {lines.map(({x1, x2, y1, y2}) => 
        <line x1={x1} x2={x2} y1={y1} y2={y2} stroke="blue" strokeWidth="2" />)
      }
      
      {points.map(({x, y}) => 
        <circle cx={x} cy={y} r="5" fill="red" />)
      }
    </svg>
  );
}


const data = [
  {x: 20, y: 100}, 
  {x: 50, y: 80},
  {x: 80, y: 50}
];

ReactDOM.render(<MyChart points={data} />, document.querySelector("#container"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```